# Hidden Folders still showing in gallery

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide from gallery all my application's images . What I did was to use a "." in my root folder to hide this, but after  that my gallery still showing my hidden as shown in screenshot. How can I remove it programatically?? Is there a better way to remove this images from gallery than hide the folder?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place a file called ".nomedia" in the folders you wish to hide.

If you want to programmatically hide images, your best bet is encryption or changing the file extensions (eg, myPic.jpg -> myPic.data)

You may also need to refresh your gallery for these changes to take place.

Comment: this file .nomedia will hide all media files from child folders too?

Comment: rename images in my case is not a good option, because is more than 2 GB images that can be downloaded anytime and they have dependencies